# how to implement a pseudocode for a search algorithm for BST

Tags: algorithm, recursion, search, tree, binary-search-tree

I've studied a bit about recursion and I implemented what I learned on a binary search tree. I have a successful search and an unsuccessful search as my base case, and the algorithm function takes two parameters as input - one is the key that we are searching for in the binary search tree, and the other is the node that we are propagating the search from. The problem lies on formulating a pseudocode that answers the question.

I did the following approach - some said that it's wrong as I don't need the "@return" statement when I did the recursive call on either a node's left or right child but I argued that this is correct as we are expecting something out of that recursive function call and that if we remove the "@return" statement it will remove the recursive stack trace to the original caller of that function that begins the recursion and that node calling the search_bst(k, v) function will not have anything to return.

```
function search_bst(k, v):
   if v.isExternal():
      return v
   if k = key(v):
      return v
   # search the left sub-tree
   else if k < key(v):
      return search(k, v.left)
   # search the right sub-tree
   else k > key(v):
      return search(k, v.right)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right that the `return` is needed for the reasons you have given.

Here are some comments on the code you presented:

- The method `isExternal` is not intuitive to me. It could be interpreted to mean `isLeaf`, or it could mean that your tree is defined with explicit `NIL` objects that have this method and only in that case return true. The latter interpretation would be a bit odd, as in real object oriented languages, null represents the *absence* of an object/pointer, and so you wouldn't have a method to call.
- If `isExternal` means `isLeaf`, then this algorithm would not work when the BST is empty (has no nodes). And secondly, it would then be wrong to `return v`, as that would return a node that does *not* have the desired key.
- The final case (`k > key(v)`) should not have to be tested, as it is the only other possibility left.

I would therefore rewrite the code like this:

```py
function search_bst(k, v):
   if isNull(v) or k = key(v):
      return v
   else if k < key(v):
      # search the left sub-tree
      return search(k, v.left)
   else:
      # search the right sub-tree
      return search(k, v.right)
```

Comment: Hi - `isExternal` here means whether it is a dummy node or not (i.e. in the event of an unsuccessful search return that dummy node a.k.a. NULL). I probably should have said that v is equal to NULL (or v == NULL). also the else points to k >= key(v) not just k > key(v), just pointing this out. but other than that, thank you for the fix!

Comment: Yes, I thought it could have meant that. I have expressed my thoughts about that. The notation `v.someMethod` strongly suggests that `v` is an *object* that has this method, yet in most actual languages a `NULL` does not have methods. Anyway, this doubt is taken away with an `isNull` function, much like you have the `key` function.

Comment: edit: I'm stupid to think that the k == key(v) is not handled on a separate if branch, which led to me saying that k = key(v). anyways unrelated question: how do you study for a system's programming course? the course is run on C, and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: "How to study" is a question that is more for teachers to answer. I am not in a position to advise you on that.

Comment: that's sad, and here am I thinking that you've earned the title as a `teacher` because you've basically taught me something, by correcting my mistakes.

Comment: Yes, I think I am in a position to teach about programming, but not about learning. It's a different field of expertise. People who are teachers by profession have (I hope) the skills to advise on how to study. I'm not that guy.